# Making a 5 second timer for a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a crap version of flappy bird just for pratice and I want to spawn pipes in increments based on time, so I can then later start removing time to make it prgressively harder.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pipe_Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pipesPrefab;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    public float secsToNext -= Time.deltaTime// public lets you check it running in the inspector
    { 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()//every single frame its called
    {
        secsToNext -= Time.deltaTime;  // T.dt is secs since last update
        if(secsToNext<=5) {
        secsToNext = Random.Range(8.0f, 12.0f);
        float Vertical = Random.Range(1.0f, 6.0f);
        float Horizontal = Random.Range(-7.0f, 7.0f);
        Instantiate(pipesPrefab, new Vector2(Vertical,Horizontal), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
}
```

my errors showing up in unity are:

Assets\pipe_Spawner.cs(13,29): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Assets\pipe_Spawner.cs(13,32): error CS1002: ; expected

Assets\pipe_Spawner.cs(14,5): error CS1519: Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Assets\pipe_Spawner.cs(27,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

In that order if it matters

right now the coordinates are random purely for testing purposes.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `public float secsToNext -= Time.deltaTime`. Aafter that line you have an open curly brace for no reason and one closing curly brace at the end of the file.

Comment: I removed the brackets you meantioned, and I put a semicolon after 'public float secsToNext -= Time.deltaTime' I am still left with missing semicolon on that line it says.

Comment: The errors after making that change are
,
Assets\pipe_Spawner.cs(13,29): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
,
Assets\pipe_Spawner.cs(13,32): error CS1002: ; expected
,
Assets\pipe_Spawner.cs(13,46): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: It's because you're creating a variable and immediately trying to subtract a value from it.

Comment: Do you sugest I subtraact it in a different line of code?

Comment: Looks like you're already subtracting in the first line of the `Update` method, but you never gave it an initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare the variable secsToNext first before you subtract something from it. i would recommend to spawn a set of pipes at the start and also set the value for secsToNext in the start method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pipe_Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pipesPrefab;
    public float secsToNext;
    
    void Start() //Instantiating the pipes and set the secsToNext at the start
    {
        secsToNext = Random.Range(8.0f, 12.0f);
        float Vertical = Random.Range(1.0f, 6.0f);
        float Horizontal = Random.Range(-7.0f, 7.0f);
        Instantiate(pipesPrefab, new Vector2(Vertical,Horizontal), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        secsToNext -= Time.deltaTime;  // T.dt is secs since last update
        if(secsToNext <= 5)
        {
            secsToNext = Random.Range(8.0f, 12.0f);
            float Vertical = Random.Range(1.0f, 6.0f);
            float Horizontal = Random.Range(-7.0f, 7.0f);
            Instantiate(pipesPrefab, new Vector2(Vertical,Horizontal), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```